# Simple Beam Worst Case Scenario

Tags: statics, structural-beam

## Part 1

If I have a simple beam with two supports and a static load, does placing the load in the center push the beam closest to breaking (catastrophic failure)?

Will this be more likely to break the beam:

```
           F
___________v___________
^                     ^
P1                   P2
```

Or this:

```
                  F
__________________v____
^                     ^
P1                   P2
```

Or some other configuration?

## Part 2

This may be more complicated.  Which of these configurations pushes the beam closer to breaking:

- A floating beam (not attached at P1 & P2)
- A fixed beam (attached at P1 & P2)

Which of these should I use in my worst case calculations?

### I do not care about deflection.

Comment: I am a handy man who knows a little bit of math, but no engineering.  I apologize if my question is ignorant. Any keywords or phrases that I should be researching to improve my understanding and improve the question are welcome.  Side Note: I am accounting for safety factors and calculating static and dynamic loads.

Comment: Typically on this site we won't do 'engineering'. I think your two basic questions (is a force near the edge or the middle more likely to break the beam; what effect does fixing the ends have) are good physics questions, but the extra info about beam materials and properties is unnecessary, the physics answer to this problem will just assume an idealized generic beam. If you're more interested in the engineering aspects of this scenario, you might try one of the engineering SE sites instead.

Comment: @KyleOman Thanks, I removed it.  I thought those numbers might be relevant because I was trying to avoid getting "It depends." as an answer.

Comment: You can figure it out. Hint: Try moving F all the way over to P1 or P2.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I intuitively get that, but I want some reassurance.  I also am not sure if a fixed beam changes that; that's why I asked this in Parts instead of two seperate questions.

Comment: I, too, think this is a very nice physics question. We all know the answer but I do not know and can, for now, not think of a simple logical way of deriving it using basic principles of mechanics. One could, of course, calculate the forces along the beam (or look up the calculation in an engineering textbook), but it seems that there should be a simple and maybe even congenial way of doing it without going trough the math. I am looking forward to seeing it, myself. My current guess is that a logical derivation will probably split the beam into two parts and be  recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bending stress is greatest in the middle; and when the ends are clamped, the stress is less than if they are free to bend.

All this is captured in the equations for bending moment of a beam - a (pretty) complete set of these can be found at http://www.awc.org/pdf/DA6-BeamFormulas.pdf

For part 1, you can use figure 7 (load at center):

[image]

and when the load is off center, you use figure 8:

[image]

For Part 2, beam clamped at both ends, use their figure 24:

[image]

Any other load configuration you can dream up - it's probably in there too.

Comment: So you're saying that a fixed beam will hold more because M_max is 1/2 of a floating beam's M_max for the same P (force) and l (length)? M_max is ft-lbs (or N*m)?

Comment: Yes - $M_{max}$ is the maximum bending moment, which is the thing that causes your beam to break (assuming the beam is uniform). The units will be determined by the units you use in your calculation. I always use SI so I don't get confused (and then the result will be in Nm).

Comment: Ok, awesome.  Before I accept: Are there any other factors that I'm overlooking?  Is $M_{max}$ the only important property here?

Comment: Obviously the local strength of the beam matters a great deal: anything that causes "stress concentration" (cuts, nicks, fractures, changing section) will greatly diminish the strength. But if you have a uniform beam and a support that does not cut into it, then these formulas are pretty good.